# Why is there a God rather than nothing?

Tags: metaphysics, theology, ontology, cosmology

Theists ask, "Why is there something rather than nothing?"  How would they answer the question, "Why is there a God rather than nothing?"  Is this a valid objection to theism?

Comment: I should probably have asked, "Have any philosophers ever attempted to answer this question?"  If so, who?

Comment: Of all the approaches to God’s existence, the deduction is the strategy that we would expect to be successful were there a necessary God. But there are not a valid deduction, then we can conclude that there is no such necessary God.

Comment: There is no deduction here, only a question.

Comment: No, not particularly. They're the same question, roughly speaking.

Comment: Why is there something, the universe or God, rather than nothing? This is an illogical nonsense question and not a quest of evidence because impose an impossible explanatory demand, to deduce the existence of something without using any existential premise.

Comment: @Bevilaqua: Yes I agree. But with these kind of questions one is really debating what one believes, not what one can deduce. It's about the assumptions one starts with, perhaps the bedrock of your own self.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Atheists just believe in one fewer God than Christian believers. When believers understand why they refuse all the other possible Gods, they will understand why atheists reject the myth of them too. A religion rejects other religions precisely because they are faith-based, there is no evidence for them. –

Comment: Low quality question with no development or context, no indication the OP did any searching on his own, question based on a highly-contested assertion, no references to extant literature or authors... Closing pending improvements.

Answer (score 4):

If everything has a cause, then God must have a cause. If there can be anything without a cause, it may just be the universe as God. You can not give a  imaginary definition of attributes of God or a flying pink unicorn, as timeless or out space being or uncaused being, as proof of  existence. Some have argued that because the universe is like a clock, there must be a clock maker. This is a slippery argument, because there is nothing that is really perfectly analogous to the universe as a whole, if your question is about the whole, because everything is just a part of universe. The question of the creation of the universe, the whole, itself makes no sense. Time didn't exist before the universe, so there is no time for a cause to make the universe in. The concept of "before" becomes meaningless when considering a situation without time. It’s like asking directions to the edge of the earth; The earth is a sphere; it doesn't have an edge; so looking for it is a futile exercise. Why is there something, the universe or God, rather than nothing? This is an illogical question because impose an impossible explanatory demand, to deduce the existence of something without using any existential premises. Of all the approaches to God’s existence, the deduction is the strategy that we would expect to be successful were there a necessary God. But there are not a valid deduction, then we can conclude that there is no such necessary God.

Comment: The Kalam Cosmological Argument states:
   1. Everything that has a beginning of its existence has a cause of its existence;
   2. The universe has a beginning of its existence;

   Therefore:

   3. The universe has a cause of its existence.  Theists then go on to say that time and space began when the Universe began, so the first cause must have existed outside of time and space and could therefore have been causeless.  Since God didn't begin to exist it does not need a cause.  But that still doesn't explain where there is a God rather than nothing.

Comment: “The universe has a beginning, therefore the universe has a cause” Begs the question, a classic fallacy. It can be is a composition fallacy too:“Everything in the universe has a cause or/and local, then the universe has a cause or/and local”. “So the first cause must have existed ”, is appeal to ignorance fallacy: There is no evidence for p. Therefore, not-p. “Not explain where there is a God rather than nothing”, likewise about the universe, this is an illogical nonsense question because impose an impossible explanatory demand, to deduce the existence without using any existential premises.

Comment: You don't appear to understand what "begging the question" means. The above is a sound example of modus ponens. Major premise: "everything that begins to exist has a cause"; minor premise: "the universe began to exist"; the obvious conclusion of this syllogism: "therefore, the universe has a cause". Also, we're not dealing with a composition fallacy at all, only an inductive inference. Furthermore, if we assert that something can come from nothing, we have the far larger burden of explaining why we have no evidence for uncaused things. I don't understand where the appeal to ignorance comes in.

Comment: @danielm You didn't know what is an informal fallacy, It is not a formal fallacies of deductive reasoning, but it is fallacious for epistemological, dialectical, or pragmatic reasons. Wikipedia: Begging the question or assuming the point at issue is an informal fallacy. An argument begs the question when it assumes the controversial point not conceded by the other side. If “The universe began to exist” or not is the point at issue, not the premise. How  we can extrapolate the beginning of the singularity sometimes called "the Big Bang is debated.

Comment: @danielm “Appeal to ignorance" is a fallacy, is to assert that a proposition is true because it has not yet been proven false: it has not yet been proven false that universe has a first cause,  “so the first cause must have existed ”. But lack of proof is not proof.

Comment: @danielm Everything in the universe has a cause, then the universe has a cause” is a fallacy of composition because you didn't show that “has a cause”, likewise as for example “has a localization” is a property which necessarily distributes from all of the parts to the whole.Why is there something, the universe or God, rather than nothing? This is an illogical nonsense question and not a quest of evidence because impose an impossible explanatory demand, to deduce the existence of something without using any existential premise

Comment: @RicardoBevilaqua - That's not the point of issue. The point of issue is that the universe has a cause. You can attack that premise, but the argument is not a fallacious one. Second, the argument is not from parts, but an inductive inference from a sample of a class i.e. things which began to exist. It does not reason from parts to whole, which would be fallacious, but from some members of a class to all members of a class. Note the difference. Third, I know what an appeal to ignorance is, thank you. But I don't see it as applicable here. There are other points worth examining.

Comment: @danielm A  premise “"the universe began to exist" “ of your syllogism is the point at issue, this is the informal fallacy of begging the question.  “An inductive inference from a sample of a class i.e. things which began to exist”:  The universe is the class of “things which began to exist”, then it is member of itself. It is not a valid inference. The human body is the class of microscopic human cells, then it is member of itself. Fallacious. We don't know the cause of universe,  God is the best cause to explain the universe, then God exist. Appeal to ignorance fallacy.

Comment: @RicardoBevilaqua - Ever hear of the Big Bang? And it's not the point of issue, it's a premise, and it differs from the conclusion. Also, if the universe is only the class of things that began to exist, and not a thing itself, then it follows that the composition fallacy becomes impossible in the accused way because then you're only talking about the parts that do come to exist because no universe exists to speak of except as arrangement of parts. The word "universe" merely becomes a name for things which you have inductively accepted as coming into being. Please see mereology nihilism.

Comment: @danielm If “the universe began to exist”  is the point at issue, not the premise. The Big Bang theory is only one of possible cosmologies. Ever hear of the quantum and string cosmologies? We do not know yet if the best model will predict a finitely old universe, but there are good reasons to think that the big bang is not necessarily an absolute beginning. “It does reason from some members of a class of “things which began to exist” to all members of the class”. It is your bizarre conception of universe not mine.

Comment: @RicardoBevilaqua - Final comment - 1: "Point of issue" is in relation to the argument, not its truth. 2: Yes, it is one of a few possible cosmologies, but it's not my conception, nor my argument. I'm refuting attacks on its soundness, not its veracity. 3: No, you reduced the universe to a composition of parts. Therefore, the composition fallacy you originally submitted can't even work. Perhaps you have a bizarre metaphysics.

Comment: @danielm Final comment -1: If the point of issue is not in relation the truth, why bother with the argument? 2: If there isn't veracity why bother with soundness? 3: No, you want a contingent universe by the composition of contingent parts. Perhaps you want theological metaphysics. Atheists just believe in one fewer God than Christian believers. When believers understand why they refuse all the other possible Gods, they will understand why atheists reject the myth of them too. A religion rejects other religions precisely because they are faith-based, there is no evidence for them.

Answer (score 0):

My view is that the question "Why is there something rather than nothing?" is answerable.  The conclusion I've come to is that "something" and "nothing" are just two different words or ways of looking at the same underlying thing: what we've traditionally thought of as the "absolute lack-of-all", or "non-existence".  That is, the universe, or "something", must exist because even if there were "nothing at all", this "nothingness" can be thought of from a different perspective as being an existent state, or "something".   A slightly less brief summary of my arguments for this are below and [here](https://sites.google.com/site/ralphthewebsite/filecabinet/why-things-exist-something-nothing).

But, given this, I admit that I can never prove my arguments because no one can step outside our existence spatially or temporally to see what caused it.  Instead, what I'm trying to do is to use the rationale as a base to try and build a working model of the universe that can eventually make testable predictions via a process that I call "philosophical engineering".  Predictably, I'm a long way from this goal!   Thank you for listening.

From the abstract of a paper I wrote at my website on the questions "Why do things exist?" and "Why is there something rather than nothing?":

In this paper, I propose solutions to the questions "Why do things exist?" and "Why is there something rather than nothing?"  In regard to the first question, "Why do things exist?", it is argued that a thing exists if it is a grouping, or collection.  A grouping is some relationship saying, or defining, what is contained within.  Such a definition or grouping is equivalent to an edge, boundary, or enclosing surface defining what is contained within and giving "substance" and existence to the thing.  An example of a grouping, and thus an existent state, is a set.  Without a relationship defining what elements are contained within a set, the set would not exist.  This relationship, or grouping is shown by the curly braces, or edge, around the elements of the set, and is what gives existence to the set.  In regard to the second question, "Why is there something rather than nothing?", "absolute nothing", or "non-existence", is first defined to 
mean: no energy, matter, volume, space, time, thoughts, concepts, mathematical truths, etc.; and no minds to think about this absolute lack-of-all.   This absolute lack-of-all itself, not our mind's conception of the absolute lack-of-all, is the entirety or whole amount of all that is present. This lack-of-all, in and of itself, defines the entirety of all that is present.  It says exactly what's there.  An entirety, or whole amount, or everything, is a relationship defining what is contained within (ie., everything) and is therefore a grouping,  or edge, and, therefore, an existent state.  This edge is not some separate thing; it is just the relationship, inherent in the absolute lack-of-all, defining what is contained within.  Therefore, what has traditionally been thought of as "absolute lack-of-all", "nothing", or "non-existence", is, when seen from this different perspective, a grouping, and thus an existent state or "something".  Said yet another way, "non-existence" can appear 
as either "nothing" or "something" depending on how the observer thinks about it.   Another argument is then presented that reaches this same conclusion.  Finally, this reasoning is used to form a primitive, causal set- or cellular automaton-like model of the universe via what I refer to as "philosophical engineering".

Additional non-abstract note: One mistake that both academic and non-academic philosophers make in this area is to confuse the mind's conception of non-existence with non-existence itself, in which neither the mind nor anything else is present.  Because our minds exist, our mind's conception of non-existence is dependent on existence; that is, we must define non-existence as the lack of existence.  But, non-existence itself, and not our mind's conception of non-existence, does not have this requirement; it is independent of our mind, and of existence, and of being defined as the lack of existence.  Non-existence itself is on its own, and on its own, completely describes the entirety of what is there and is thus an existent state.  That is,  what we've always called "non-existence" really isn't non-existent at all; when thought of in this different way, one can see that it's actually an existent state and, indeed, is the most fundamental of existent 
states.

Another argument that reaches the same conclusion to the question "Why is there something rather than nothing is:

1.) In regard to the question "Why is there something rather than nothing?”, two choices for addressing this question are

```
   A. "Something” has always been here. 

   B. "Something” has not always been here.
```

Choice A is possible but does not explain anything (however, it will be discussed more at the end of this section).  Therefore, choice B is the only choice with any explanatory power.   So, this choice will be explored to see where it leads. With choice B, if “something” has not always been here, then “nothing” must have been here before it. By “nothing”, I mean complete “non-existence” (no energy, matter, volume, space, time, thoughts, concepts, mathematical truths, etc., and no minds to consider this complete "lack-of-all").  The mind of the reader trying to visualize this would be gone as well.  But, in this "absolute nothing”, there would be no mechanism present to change this “nothingness” into the “something” that is here now. Because we can see that “something” is here now, the only possible choice then is that “nothing” and “something” are one and the same thing. This is logically required if we go with choice B.

Answer (score -1):

This is basically the rebuttal to the first-cause argument. If the universe had a first-cause (God), then what caused God to exist?

Since the creator of the universe must be more complex than its creation (that's what's usually assumed), this is not the best explanation. In other words, it's easier to explain how the universe came into being (without God), then how a God with such capacity came into being. Another well-established concept in science is that you favor the least complex hypothesis, unless there is a good reason to favor a more complex hypothesis. This is called ["Ockham's Razor"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor).

Comment: ChaosAndOrder hits the nail on the head. Science had the fundamental problem of explaining everything by "God did it" or magic, etc. Science uses Ockham's Razor to eliminate an all powerful, all knowing force from the equation. You can YouTube Ockham's Razor to learn more about the priests who wanted to answer real questions without someone always crying because God did it.

Comment: If God created the Universe then he also created the laws of physics and laws of causality.  Why would it be necessary for God to have been caused?  He must have existed prior to the existence of time and space so he is not subject to them.  But that doesn't explain why he exists (if he does).

Comment: Why would it be necessary for universe to have been caused? If you can imagine/require a God as without cause why you cannot imagine/require an universe as without cause? You can not give a imaginary definition of attributes of  a flying pink unicorn, as a timeless or outside space being or uncaused being, as proof of its existence.

Comment: I don't think you understand the process of reasoning to what minimal properties a first cause must possess in order to account for it being a first cause for what exists. It's not a matter of positing things ad hoc. Also, if you wish to assert that something can come from nothing, then you have the burden of proof to show that it can (and thus why we don't know of anything of that sort). Also, the lack of an explanation for God does not nullify the validity of God as an explanation for the universe. Otherwise, by virtue of infinite regress, all explanation would be impossible.

Comment: @danielm  Lawrence Krauss has written a good book on how a universe can come from nothing; I highly recommend it. Anyone making a claim about the existence of something has the burden of proof on his shoulders, since a positive claim is much easier to prove than a negative one. I dont' claim God doesn't exist; I just haven't seen any evidence for his existence and I also don't see why his existence would be a good (i.e. better than the one we have now) explanation for the existence of our universe. That's all I said.

Comment: @ChaosAndOrder - I was responding to Ricardo, and not in defense of any position, but for the errors in his arguments. In any case, I'm perfectly aware of Krauss, but he does no such thing as you claim. The man can't even understand what nothing "is". He is philosophically illiterate to a point that is painful to listen to. I highly suggest you delve into some real philosophy instead of wasting your time on this dying New Atheist fad. There are far better atheists to read. Their arguments may appear original to you, but they are very old hat.

Comment: @danielm If everything has a cause, then God must have a cause. If there can be anything without a cause, it may just be the universe as God. If you can imagine  God as uncaused, why not the universe? My or your inability to invalidate the existence of Zeus or an Hindu God or your imagination, is not at all the same thing as proving it true. What can be asserted without proof can be dismissed without proof. The burden of proof lies upon a person making untestable claims.

Comment: @danielm First off, I've read a lot of philosophy and on atheism. While I agree Krauss isn't that great, philosophically speaking (his book is mainly about cosmology, though with philosophical implications), I do think it's a little arrogant to say the philosophy you like is "real philosophy" and the one you dislike is "unreal(?) philosophy". Also, your argument is one big 'ad hominem': "He is philosophically illiterate to a point that is painful to listen to" and "this dying New Atheist fad". Attack his arguments if you don't like them, not the man.

Comment: @ChaosAndOrder - First, it's not ad hominem because I wasn't providing an argument or claiming to prove anything through my remark. I was merely giving you advise. Second, it's not a matter of what philosophy I like or dislike, or a matter of arrogance. Is it arrogant to say that there is such a thing as real physics and bad physics? Certainly not. Philosophy isn't mental masturbation, contrary to popular opinion. So no, I'm afraid there is a difference between the intellectually offensive literature of Krauss and Brentano. And don't backtrack. You "highly recommend" him, after all.

Comment: @danielm Yes, I highly recommend his book, which is mainly about cosmology; I don't recommend his views on philosophy. Physics is a science, and there are criteria for what is scientific and what is not ("if it disagrees with experimental evidence, it's wrong", e.a.); the same cannot be said about philosophy; I don't see any criteria to distinguish 'real philosophy' from 'bad philosophy'.

Comment: @ChaosAndOrder: Yes, but the experimental proof might not be forthcoming for a very long time, (in the case of atoms over 2 millenia). What about String Theory and  Multiverses? Are they scientific? Physicalism doesn't *prove* the universe is self-subsistent, its an underlying assumption.

Comment: Btw, I'm not arguing for the truth of this argument. What I've been doing is pointing out that many of the accusations lodged against it are false and demonstrate a lack of familiarity with the argument and/or fallacies. W.r.t. "disagreeing with experimental evidence", I'm not sure what that means, but I refer you to Duhem and Quine. It's not as cut and dry in the way you appear to think it is. And just because you don't know what separates good phil. form bad phil. doesn't mean such criteria don't exist. Bad phil. and good science cannot coexist in a consistent mind, and vice versa.

Comment: @MoziburUllah String theory isn't scientific (yet); it is so far nothing more than the development of the so-called 'educated guess'; only the first step in becoming a scientific theory (or being rejected as such). It has to be translated into an experiment before it can become a scientific theory. Physicalism in indeed, in essence, an assumption, but a very reasonable one, I think. Why would we assume immaterial "things" to exist if we have no evidence for them? Materialism makes less assumptions than philosophical theories that claim metaphysical entities exist.

Comment: @danielm "And just because you don't know what separates good phil. form bad phil. doesn't mean such criteria don't exist" That's definitely true and I'm genuinely curious to hear what these criteria are to distinguish good philosophy from bad philosophy...

Answer (score -1):

There is something rather than nothing because the state of "nothing" is UNSTABLE.   Quantum Physics tells us that the state of “nothing” does not stay “nothing” for long.  The key to understanding creation is in knowing that gravity is actually negative energy allowing a creation from nothing where the total energy of the universe remains at zero.  Matter is the balancing positive energy.  Since the state of “nothing” is unstable, the stuff around us is the result of nature seeking stability.  Download “The Origin of the Universe – Case Closed” for more.    It’s an easy read with many pictures.

Answer (score -2):

Complexity.

The answer is not in that there is "something" but in that there is "this".

The only thing that really shakes my otherwise firm atheism is the Maxwell Equations. Things we take as normal exhibit extreme complexity under closer scrutiny.

A photon, is simultaneously a particle with a mass, and two entwined fields vibrating in a way that one wakes the other dying out, and the other then wakes the first. Look at the concept of a photon up close. Something so trivially fundamental is essentially a very complex concept.

Or take chemistry. Six quarks into three basic particles (electron, proton, neutron) into over 100 different atoms, each with unique properties arranged into a fancy grid of similarities of the periodic table, based on fancy shapes electron orbitals take under different energies.

Why is the universe so complex, ruled by rules of such elegance, simple fundamental concepts flourishing into rich variety that still retains order, though different than its parts.

Why is the universe complex rather than trivial or entirely chaotic? Why is physics so broad, and not a bunch of simple goo ruled by two-three trivial laws or a forest of inconsistent laws of which we didn't even begin to scratch the surface? Why does the simple set of fundamental rules (Maxwell Equations) explode into chemistry - a set of rules much broader but still well within our grasp, and not into endless chaos of something entirely indescribable with laws?

The belief that something of this elegance, this degree of complexity and order rooted this deeply in its laws is a product of a random accident is difficult. This specific degree of complexity, this point between triviality and chaos, suggests conscious effort to set it just at that level.

Of course it may well be that this golden middle of complexity is the prerequisite of creation of self-aware life, and there are countless other universes both more simple and overly complex but they could never develop life. Our is a set of rules that happens to breed sentient observers.

But there's no indication for or against either of these two options.